# Toyota Tacoma 2000 won't start

Tags: toyota, starting, tacoma

Sometimes after a trip (2-3 hrs) when i turn off my tacoma, won't turn on again, i knock on starter bobine it start, and sometimes don't. I replace the bobine, it's seems good for 2-3 months, then the same problem come again,i checked the starter its good.
What's the problem soo?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by a "bobine"?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 "Bobine" probably refers to the coil.